# タイトルにcontent_tagを反映させたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

threddedというフォーラム機能のgemを導入し、設定中です。

タイトル表示用に、:thredded_page_title
というcontent_tagが用意されています。

レイアウトファイルのbody内で、
<%= yield :thredded_page_title %>
とすると、問題なく表示されます。

ただ、現在、アプリケーション全体で、タイトルについては以下のような設定をしており、:thredded_page_titleがある場合のみ、@page_titleではなくそれを表示したいのですが、方法がわかりません。

ヘルパーやレイアウトファイルのhead内でyieldは使えない(？)、
シンボルのままでもやはりエラーになります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def page_title
    title = "テストアプリ"
    title = @page_title + " | " + title if @page_title
    title
  end
end
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<title><%= page_title %></title>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thredded`というgem自体は使ったことないのですが、
`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`で以下のようにするのが一番手軽かもしれないですねえ。

```
<%= yield(:thredded_page_title).presence || page_title %>
```